Hotkey G not working
I was trying to follow a doghnout tutorial, but every time I try to use a hotkey G for moving a vertex, it gives me error code. However, it does work when selected on tool menu. Does anyone know, why this is happening - Do I have a weird addon or...? Thank you in advence!


You can see in the error message that it's about an add-on called Lazy Viewport. You can see on its page that it re-maps standard  G , R ,  S  keys to something else:

What does it do?
A simple addon for blender to map the standard G, R, S hotkeys to the
view tools, so you don't have to use the snapping hotkeys X, Y, Z.

It seems to not function as intended. Updating it would likely fix the issue with it, but you may consider if you want to use it at all. If you want to follow tutorials that use standard key map, you should at least disable it temporarily while you are trying to follow the tutorials. You can do that in your Preferences( F4  ->  P , or Edit -> Prefernces), Add-ons tab. You can search for it by name:

Consider disabling it or removing it altogether.
I would like to suggest considering not using it at all. It remaps transform operator hotkeys to activate the matching tools. This is unnecessary since you can hit  Shift  +  Space  followed by  G , R  or  S  to activate those tools anyway and not having access to transform operators will limit you from accessing very powerful functionality of those operators. It is true that it's a preference and you can choose if you want to use the operators or tools, but since you are only learning it would be logical to first learn to use both and only then decide. If you choose to use the tools only, that add-on would make sense.

In my personal opinion that's a terrible add-on. It should not be used by beginners. It's not a fact though, just opinion, so of course you should decide for yourself.

Thank you for your feedback! I have noticed that after my little break from blender, that add-on is just on the way so I agree on disabling that.

The error seems to be related to the "Lazy Viewport" addon. You might need to update it to the latest version. If it doesn't help, try disabling the addon.

Thank you! I disabled the addon and it started working!
